# jquery dataTable TypeError: j[k] is undefined

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using jquery dataTable for list of data.
My issue is that when page it load is returnig TypeError: j[k] is undefined.
My getStudentDataTable.json is not get loaded.

My Jquery code is like this :

```
   $(document).ready(funDemo);
            function funDemo() {
                $('#listTable').dataTable({

                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/getStudentDataTable.json",
                    "aoColumns": [ 
                        {mData: "Student.id"},
                        {mData: "Student.stud_name"},
                        {mData: "Student.Roll_no"},


                    ],
                    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                        $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html("<input onclick='return editContact(" + JSON.stringify(aData.Student) + ");' type='button' value='Edit'>");
                        $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html("<input onclick='return deleteContact(" + JSON.stringify(aData.Student) + ");' type='button' value='Delete'>");
                        //$('td:eq(4)', nRow).html('<a href="/contacts/view/'+aData.Contact.id+'">'+aData.Contact.email+'</a>');
                    }

                });
}
```

Json data :

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 9,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 9,
    "aaData": [
        {
            "Contact": {
                "id": "2",
                "fname": "gaurav",
                "rollno": "201",

            }
        },

        {
            "Contact": {
                "id": "5",
                "fname": "abhishek",
                "rollno": "202",

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Html table is defind :

```
  <table id="listTable" border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Stud name</th>
                        <th>roll no</th>
                        <th colspan='2'>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the 2 lines in `fnCreatedRow`?

Comment: Its working fine with out fnCreatedRow.

Comment: I have solve this issue. m giving colspan=2 <th colspan='2'>Action</th> so that is makes problem.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem and spent almost 1 hour to fix it. Solution is very simple. I just had to add one column `<td>` to my `HTML -> TABLE` and issue got fixed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some code?  Where did you add the td exactly?  Inside <thead><tr>?  In a new <tbody>?

Comment: This works for me. I accidentally added row with wrong `<td>`s.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I just make sure the number of head and body column is the same. For example the **targets** `dataTable` does not exceed the number of column heads.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="listTable" border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Stud name</th>
                        <th>roll no</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

I have removed colspan.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the dataSrc variable in ajax definition name, mismatch with the returned json name in my controller class.
For example:

```
echo json_encode(['status' => true, 'data' => $taskList]);
```

Ensure in you ajax you refer to **data** as the **dataSrc**